# Nested Java hashmap to nested Scala map conversion

Tags: scala

What is the right way to convert a variable of type `java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.util.List<java.lang.String>>` in Java, to its Scala equivalent: `Map[Map[String, List[String]]]`? (with Scala `Map`, `String` and `List`)

I tried to use `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._` and do `JavaNestedMap.asScala` but it failed. Is there a smart way of doing this (rather than having two `map`s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single call way I know of.

This is succinct likely inefficient in a hot loop. Profile if it ends up being too slow and then you'd want to use builders directly.

```
val in: JMap[JMap[String, String]] = ???
val out: Map[Map[String, String]] = in.asScala.mapValues(_.asScala)
val again: JMap[JMap[String, String]] = out.map(_.asJava).asJava
```

It's worth noting that `.asScala` gives you a mutable map for consistency with the java map. If you want to get an immutable map back, you need to call `.toMap` afterwords.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Though I think it is better to write the last two steps   like this: 
`in.asScala.map{item => (item._1, item._2.asScala.toMap)}.toMap` . `toMap` is to convert it to Scala's `immutable` map.